# How do I stub a response for an Angular $resource that depends on an external service?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

How do I stub a response instead of querying $resource that depends on an external service? I'm getting an error: `Error: Unexpected request: GET data/counties.json`

Here's my service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory("geoProvider", function($resource){
    return {
      states: $resource('data/states.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
      }),
      counties: $resource('data/counties.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
      })
   };
});
```

Spec:

```
describe('service', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

    describe('geoProvider', function() {
    it('should return data / JSON', inject(function(geoProvider){
      var data = geoProvider.counties.query();
     expect(data).toBe(some);
    }));

  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject *$httpBackend* into your tests and configure it to expect the requests you need:

```
describe('service', function() {
    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    it('should return data / JSON', inject(function(geoProvider){
        $httpBackend.expectGET('yoururl').respond({/* the response object */});

        var data = geoProvider.counties.query();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(data).toBe(some);
    }));
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a $httpBackend is not defined.

Comment: EDIT: it's defined now. But what goes into respond?

Comment: `$httpBackend.expectGET('data/states.json').respond(_____);
`
Do I write my own object that imitates the object (JSON) that the service returns?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that.